# Is there a way to filter 'local' duplicates with SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table of messages sent by either a customer or a provider, representing a conversation through an instant messaging app:

| id | sender_type | date_sent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CUSTOMER | 2023-01-04 |
| 2 | PROVIDER | 2023-01-13 |
| 3 | CUSTOMER | 2023-01-21 |
| 4 | CUSTOMER | 2023-01-28 |
| 5 | CUSTOMER | 2023-02-02 |
| 6 | PROVIDER | 2023-02-04 |
| 7 | PROVIDER | 2023-02-05 |

My goal is to compute the average response time of the provider, e.g. the time between a customer's message and the next provider's message.
The problem is that both can send several messages in a row, and I would need a way to get rid of those to consider only the first message of each group. In my example, I only need entries 1, 2, 3 and 6.

I cannot see a way to trim this data down to what I need within an SQL query. Thanks in advance for the help.

(edit) The database is on PostgreSQL 14.6. Expected result:

| id | sender_type | date_sent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CUSTOMER | 2023-01-04 |
| 2 | PROVIDER | 2023-01-13 |
| 3 | CUSTOMER | 2023-01-21 |
| 6 | PROVIDER | 2023-02-04 |

And with this data, I could compute and average of (9+14)/2 = 11.5 days

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (sql server, mysql, postgres, etc)? This feels like a "Gaps and islands" problems.

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result. (Same format as the sample table data.)

Comment: Edited with both. I didn't know about the "gaps and islands" problem, it indeed seems like what I want. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH CTE as (SELECT
   `id`, `sender_type`, `date_sent`,
CASE WHEN sender_type <> LAG(sender_type) OVER( ORDEr BY `date_sent` ) OR LAG(sender_type) OVER( ORDEr BY `date_sent` ) iS NuLL then 1 ELSe 0 END rk
FROM tab1),
CTE2 as (
  SELECT `id`, `sender_type`, `date_sent`,
  SUM(rk) OVER(ORDEr BY `date_sent`) rk
  FROM CTE
  ), CTE3 As
( 
  SELECT `id`, `sender_type`, `date_sent`,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rk ORDEr BY `date_sent`) rk
  FROM CTE2)
SELECT
 `id`, `sender_type`, `date_sent`
FROM CTE3 where rk = 1
```

| id | sender_type | date_sent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CUSTOMER | 2023-01-04 |
| 2 | PROVIDER | 2023-01-13 |
| 3 | CUSTOMER | 2023-01-21 |
| 6 | PROVIDER | 2023-02-04 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AuYE7gwS)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LAG function to get values from the prior row in a set, and then use that to figure out the difference in dates when a message is from a provider and the prior message was from a customer.  Like this:

```
with 
    t as (
        select
            id,
            sender_type,
            date_sent,
            case lag(sender_type) over (order by id) 
                when sender_type then 0
                else 1
            end as first_in_group
        from
            messages m
    ),
    t2 as (
        select
            id,
            sender_type,
            date_sent,
            lag(date_sent) over (order by id) as prior_date_sent
        from
            t
        where
            first_in_group = 1
    )
select
    avg(date_sent - prior_date_sent) as avg_provider_response_days
from
    t2
where
    sender_type = 'PROVIDER'
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h3HxqTYSt3ZB14ePoMs4nY/1

Comment: You need to fix your where clause to get the output OP wants as `WHERE sender_type <> COALESCE(prior_sender_type, 'A')`

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I don't think so, he wants the time between a CUSTOMER message and the PROVIDER response

Comment: Jus read the last line of his first paragraph - `In my example, I only need entries 1, 2, 3 and 6.`

Comment: Yes, in order to calculate the differences between 1 and 2, and 3 and 6.  Although mine calculates difference between 5 and 6 instead.

Comment: I didn't know about the LAG function, this might work out, although it is always the first message in a group that counts. And indeed, I only care about the time from a CUSTOMER message to a PROVIDER one. Thank you both

Comment: @7evy I updated the query to first identify the initial record in a group, then calculate the prior date from only the initials, and finally calculate the average response time